# Cannot add DNN Module Template to VS2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, visual-studio-2008, dotnetnuke

I have changed my laptop and I'm now running XP with VS2008 using C# and DNN 6.2 When I download the DNN Starter Kit I install it but when I run VS2008 the DNN Module Template still isn't there so I cannot create any DNN Modules. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the Starter Kit for DotNetNuke has never really worked.

I have an open source template project, but I don't think I've ever done any releases for VS2008, by now everyone is using at least 2010 or 2012. You can download VS 2012 Express for Web and use my templates https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/releases/view/104508

The older releases on the codeplex page have some that work for VS2010, but all the 2.* releases are 2012 only.